# Change upc value in my Prestashop database

Tags: php, database, prestashop

All products in my Prestashop have 0 value in UPC field, but I don't have time to change them 1 by 1, so I need help to set null value in UPC field in all products at once using Database Query.

Comment: `update tablename set columname='whatever';` with no where clause will update every row. so be careful!

Answer (score 0):

`` UPDATE `ps_product` SET `upc`= [YOUR_VALUE] WHERE `upc` = 0; ``

should do the trick. Untested - Please always do a backup of your database before doing stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your `_DB_PREFIX_` var is `ps_`, you can in `settings.inc.php` in the config folder (Until PrestaShop 1.6)

If you want set to `NULL`:

`` UPDATE `ps_product` SET upc=NULL WHERE `upc`=0; ``

If you want to set to empty:

`` UPDATE `ps_product` SET upc='' WHERE `upc`=0; ``

If your products have combinations:

`` UPDATE `ps_product_attribute` SET upc=NULL WHERE `upc`=0; `` (NULL here)

or

`` UPDATE `ps_product_attribute` SET upc='' WHERE `upc`=0; `` (empty here)